# WordPress - functions.php causing WordPress error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following folder structure for my theme:

```
theme
   inc
      theme
         functions.php
      init.php
   functions.php
```

In **inc/theme/functions.php**, I'm placing all theme specific functions (i.e. removing taxonomies etc). In **theme/functions.php**, I have all my core functions.

With my current code, WordPress states "The site is experiencing technical difficulties.". If I delete everything in **theme/functions.php**, the content loads, but the code in **inc/theme/functions.php** is not being executed. For example, in **inc/theme/functions.php**, I have `wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );` and none of the styles are pulling through.

Can't seem to figure out:

1. Why **theme/functions.php** is causing a WordPress error.
2. Why **inc/theme/functions.php** is not being executed.

**theme/functions.php**

```
<?php

require_once trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'inc/init.php';

new theme_ThemeFunctions;
class theme_ThemeFunctions {

    function __construct() {
        load_theme_textdomain( 'theme' );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'post_types_taxonomies' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_menus' ) );
    }

    public function post_types_taxonomies() {
        register_post_type(
            'case-studies',
            build_post_args(
                 'case-study', 'Case study', 'Case studies',
                 array(
                    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-book',
                    'menu_position' => 20,
                    'has_archive'   => true
                 )
            )
        );
    }

    public function register_menus() {
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'main'   => __( 'Main Menu', 'theme' ),
            )
        );
    }

}

?>
```

**inc/theme/functions.php**

```
<?php

function scriptAndStyles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scriptAndStyles' );

function remove_editor() {
  remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_editor');

// Remove featured image option from pages 
function remove_thumbnail_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv','page', 'side' );
}
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'remove_thumbnail_box');

// Remove posts type option
function post_remove () { 
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'post_remove'); 

?>
```

**inc/init.php**

```
<?php

$include_dir = trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'inc/';

// Load any custom functions
require_once $include_dir . 'theme/functions.php';

?>
```

Comment: Check the [error log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to find out what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `get_template_directory()` for require your files.

And use `new theme_ThemeFunctions` below class itself.

Also use to view errors:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', 1);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', 1);
```